# Three table query using Linq/Lambda in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have three tables

- `start`  (Id, acctId, detailId)
- `detail` (Id, name)
- `item` (Id, detailId, desc)

`start` has a one-to-one relationship with `detail`, and `detail` has a one-to-many relation with `item`.

I am trying to write a lambda or linq query so for a given `acctId`, I get `name` and `desc`. I have tried the following using EF but the result is incorrect:

```
var te = DbContext.Set<start>().Include("detail")
                  .Where(a=>a.acctId== id && a.detail.items.Any());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have navigation properties, and you only want those specific properties:

```
var te = DbContext.Set<start>().Where(a => a.acctId == id).Select(s => new
     {
         name = s.detail.name,
         descs = s.detail.items.Select(i => i.desc).ToList()
     });
```

There's a possibility you have more underlying issues as well, though...